Terraform Import Issue
I am facing an issue with importing modules in Terraform. Specifically, I am trying to import module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"], but in the state list, I found module.st_logic_apps.data.azurerm_storage_account.main["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]. Similarly, for the logic app, I am importing module.st_logic_apps.azurerm_logic_app_standard.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"], but found module.st_logic_apps.data.azurerm_subnet.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"] in the state list. This discrepancy is causing confusion.
Here is the import command I am using:
terraform import -var-file="./variables/test/variables.tfvars" 'module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]' /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/pn-re-tst-us-c-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/pnretstuscstlafiltersto7

The state list shows:
module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]
module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_storage_account.main["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]
module.st-logic-apps.azurerm_logic_app_standard.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"]
module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_subnet.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"]

It should import into module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"] while importing the storage account. But now it's importing here module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_storage_account.main["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]

The question is pretty vague. There is no code in the question, we have no idea where the modules are coming from, how are they written, how are you calling them etc.

Please see [ask]. Your post needs improvement.

please add the code you tried and and error description so that it can help in better understanding @vishashsharma

Apologies, I added it in proper manner

please provide the code configuration as well because for importing a resource into your configuration requries a setup that exactly matche @vikashsharma

I have Provided the Import command


Import Issue while using terraform

Data sources are used to reference existing resources without managing them, here we don't need to specify the info related to resource. while resource blocks are used for managing resources. Make sure you're importing into actual resource blocks and not data sources.
This is where we youre facing the blocker i.e., referencing the resource to import configuration.
Here from the query it was clear that youre importing a storage account into module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"], but the state contains a reference to module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_storage_account.main["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"], which is a data source and similar thing was happening with Logic App.
This action might be led to State inconsistency. Which is not at all good for state file to set up a match with configuration. Since youre trying to import make sure the configuration matches with the resource info.
Once the checking the configuration was done check the list of resources in the state file by running the command.
terraform state list

From the list of resources remove the data module resources.
terraform state rm 'module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_storage_account.main["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]'
terraform state rm 'module.st-logic-apps.data.azurerm_subnet.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"]'

Now re-import the resource to the correct module path
terraform import -var-file="./variables.tfvars" 'module.st-storage-account.azurerm_storage_account.storage["pnretstuscstlafiltersto7"]' /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/pn-re-tst-us-c-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/pnretstuscstlafiltersto7

This should be for the storage account
terraform import -var-file="./variables.tfvars" 'module.st_logic_apps.azurerm_logic_app_standard.main["pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance"]' /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/pn-re-tst-us-c-rg/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/pn-re-tst-us-c-st-la-com-maintenance

This should be for the Logic App.
Now continue with the commands terraform refresh, terraform apply.
Refer:
Terraform import module state - Stack Overflow by Martin Atkins
How to use terraform import with passed-in variables?
you can check with these on how to refer the resource using Import command from these.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import
